# Search for a mention of each filename contained in a directory, in every file in the directory

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to perform a search in my directory, to count the total number of times each individual file is referenced within the contents of all the files in the directory.

Essentially, I'm trying to more efficiently recreate the copy and paste of each 'filename' into the 'search in this folder' that I am currently doing, as there are around 400 files. As an output, I think the most useful format would be a list of each search term (filename), and the number of unique files that it occurs in. I am most interested in the files that have no occurrences, as these are likely to be able to be deleted, as they are now redundant.

My current thinking is to save a list of the filenames to a file called searchterms, and use `grep -r -f searchterms` to find all occurrences of the file. I've not had much luck with this however, as my use of `-c` so far has just resulted in the file being listed, not the search term.

Thanks in advance!

Example of usage:

**file1**
include file3
include file3

**file2**
content

**file3**
content

**file4**
include file3

Search terms would be: file1, file2, file3, file4.

**Returned output (in some similar form):**
file1: occurs in 0 files
file2:  occurs in 0 files
file3: occurs in 2 files
file4: occurs in 0 files

Comment: Can you give a solid example?

Comment: Typically, if you downvote, you should at least add a comment with a reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for f1 in *; do cnt=0; for f2 in *; do grep -qw "$f1" "$f2" && ((++cnt)); done; echo "$cnt $f1"; done 
1 abc-file
0 abc.lst
1 abc0-file
1 abc_-file
0 def-file
0 fixedlen
0 num1000000
0 num128
0 num30000
0 num8
0 num_%header
0 par-test.sh
0 tsv-file.tsv
```

Human readable:

```
for f1 in *
do
    cnt=0
    for f2 in *
    do
       grep -qw "$f1" "$f2" && ((++cnt))
    done
    echo "$cnt $f1"
done
```

Putting the hit counter first in the output makes for a simpler sort -n command. For high numbers of matches (>9) printf would help providing a clear tabular format.

Grep -m 1 stops searching after the first hit but is implied by -q. To not match file31 when looking for file3, -w is used. For all the misses, the files get searched from begin to end over and over again. Depending on the number of files, this might be a significant amount of time, making better optimization necessary.

Comment: This looks great, is there a way to expand upon this so that it could use the files of subdirectories as search terms, and also search within those subdirectories? Thanks!

Comment: That's a new question. Ask a new question, and you can upvote all great looking answer here, and all the ones there. In general you should consider upvoting great looking answers if you understand the purpose of upvoting and accepting answers. You may link for clarification to this question and invite us with a link to the new one, but the chances are high that we find it anyway, the same way we found this one. But the motivation to answer declines, when the only gratification is more, new work offered.

Comment: @userunknown: `-m1` is implied by `-q`.   Also, using a `-w` flag is advisable as this would prevent hits from `#include "another_file1.h"` and such.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for file in *; do 
    n=0
    for file2 in *; do
        [ grep -wq "$file" "$file2" ] && ((n+=1))
    done
    echo $file occurs in $n files
done
```

This counts self-references -- if you don't want that you can guard against it by prepending `[[ "$file1" -ne "$file2" ]] &&` to the grep line above.